# Удаление/исключение элементов списка по индексам, полученным из значений другого списка

Tags: python, list, индексы

Как исправить? Получается пройти цикл должен один раз, и сразу перезаписываться по нужному условию, у меня проходит много раз.

---

Дано два списка:

```
zone=[2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
dupdup=[1, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Список ***dupdup***, содержит номера индексов, которые нужно -*удалить/исключить/не записывать*- из списка ***zone***.

```
newzone=[]
for i,x in enumerate(zone):
    for k in (dupdup):
        if k!=i:
            newzone.append(x)
print("newzone",newzone)
```

На выходе получается:

---

newzone [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9].

---

А должно получиться так:

---

newzone [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9].

Comment: Второй цикл не нужен, вместо него `if i not in dupdup:`

Comment: Спасибо!!!!@CrazyElf

Answer (score 1):

Лучше преобразовать `list` - `dupdup` в `set` и проверять находится ли `index` в множестве, так как:

- Проверка `in list` занимает `О(n)` времени, т.е при каждой проверке `in` будет проверяться каждый элемент находящийся в списке пока не найдется искомый.
- Проверка `in set` занимает `O(1)` времени, т.е элемент находится за константное время, так элемент находится по hash значению.

И список `newzone` можно формировать с помощью [list comprehension](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/python-list-comprehension) что также ускорит работу программы

```py
zone = [2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
dupdup = {1, 4, 6, 8, 10}
newzone = [num for i, num in enumerate(zone) if i not in dupdup]
print(newzone)
```

Вывод:

```
[2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

[Временная сложность](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) - различных операций в python

Comment: Ускорит ли списковое сокращение - вопрос не однозначный. Но что код будет короче и для кого-то понятнее - это да.